# Array IndexOutOfBoundsException on Textfile Parse

Tags: java, arrays, string, parsing, text

I have a simple textfile:

```
John Jobs 225 Louis Lane Road
Amy Jones 445 Road Street
Corey Dol 556 The Road
```

Where I have people with First, last names, and address

I'm trying to parse them like this:

```
public void parseText() {

        try {
            File file = new File("test.txt");
            String[] splitted;

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                String s = sc.nextLine();
                splitted = s.split("\\s+");
                System.out.println(splitted[0]);
            }
            sc.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");        }

    }
```

splitted[0] works fine, which prints out the firstnames of the people.
splitted[1] prints out the last names, but gives me a IndexOutOfBoundsException.
spitted[2] prints out the first integer values of each address, but again gives me an exception.

So Then I tried doing this:

```
String[] splitted = new String[4];
```

and once again tried accessing any index greater than 0, but still got that problem.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried debugging?   Print out `String s` before the `split` see what it actually is getting. Then also try printing out the array `splited` after you assign it. See what it shows

Comment: Hmm, it appears to be String s, is the entire textfile(When printed out, prior to the string split).

Comment: Ahh so you must not have new line characters in the file after each line

Comment: There is a typo in your code. "splited" instead of "splitted". Please correct it.

Answer (score 0):

This is your file's content :

```
John Jobs 225 Louis Lane Road
Amy Jones 445 Road Street
Corey Dol 556 The Road
```

When each line is read and split , `splitted` will contain 6 elements for the first run and 5 for the next runs. so if you don't use indexes carefully you'll obviously get `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Better approach would be to use a foreach loop :

```
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                String s = sc.nextLine();
                splitted = s.split("\\s+");
                //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitted));
                for (String string : splitted) {
                    System.out.print(string+"  ");
                }
                System.out.println();
.....rest of code
```